# Using JApplet Form in NetBeans IDE 8.2 to create a UI for a simple rolling the dice game and outputting the result on the applet

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

This is my first time trying to create a UI in NetBeans, and I am trying to make a "game" that let's you roll two die and outputs the number respectively and tells you the sum of the die. If you get the same number on both die you get 1 out of 20 scenario stored in an array, randomly. I have gotten this part to work, however, I am trying to make it so that the output is on the applet. The code for the dice is below:

```
package dice;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random dice1 = new Random();//Rolls the die and picks a random number form 1 - 6
    Random dice2 = new Random();//""
    int number1;//""
    int number2;//""
    int add;//""
    number1 = 1+dice1.nextInt(6);//""
    number2 = 1+dice2.nextInt(6);//""
    add = number1+number2;//""
    System.out.print(number1 + " ");//""
    System.out.print(number2 + " ");//""
    System.out.println("\nYou have moved " + add + " steps!");//""
    String[] scenario = new String[20];//Stores the different scenarios if the die numbers are equivalent (20 scenarios) 
    scenario[0] = "You're an animal abuser, you are fined £500!";
    scenario[1] = "Miss a turn!";
    scenario[2] = "Grand opening, collect £100 from each player!";
    scenario[3] = "Pay vet fees of £100!";
    scenario[4] = "Recieve £25 consultancy fee!";
    scenario[5] = "You are assessed for street repairs, £25 for level 0 stop, £40 for level 1 stop, £70 for level 2 stop, £130 for level 3 stop!";
    scenario[6] = "You have won second prize in an animal beauty contest, collect £10 from every player!";
    scenario[7] = "Advance to start, collect £1000!";
    scenario[8] = "Go back three spaces!";
    scenario[9] = "Take a trip to the Lion, if you pass start collect £500!";
    scenario[10] = "Your building loan matures, collect £150!";
    scenario[11] = "You have been elected as the chairman of the board, pay each player £200!";
    scenario[12] = "Pay poor tax of £75!";
    scenario[13] = "Bank pays you dividend of £400!";
    scenario[14] = "Pay food fees of £500!";
    scenario[15] = "Miss two turns!";
    scenario[16] = "Go forward 2 spaces!";
    scenario[17] = "Your animals are satisfied, collect £100!";
    scenario[18] = "Your animals have been neglected pay, £250!";
    scenario[19] = "You are ill due to a disease from one of your animals, pay £600 as hospital fees!";
    if (number1==number2){
        int length = scenario.length;//Gets the length of teh particular string
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * length);//Random string generator
        System.out.print(scenario[rand]);//Random string generator
        System.out.println(" ");//Outputs the random scenario
    } 
}
```

This part is fine and my UI looks something like this (very simple):

[image]

Roll is a button, the small rectangle is a text area. I have created my GUI by going on source packages, and then to new and then to a JApplet Form, this created a new class in which I created the button and the text area by dragging them from the pallet.

And here are the actions for the button:

```
public class dice_interface extends javax.swing.JApplet{ 
...
private void initComponents() {

dice_roll = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    display = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    dice_roll.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 255));
    dice_roll.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cambria", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
    dice_roll.setText("Roll");

    dice_roll.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            dice_rollActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

     display.setColumns(20);
    display.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(display);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(dice_roll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 348, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 273, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(70, 70, 70))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(38, 38, 38)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 416, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(dice_roll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
}

private void dice_rollActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    } 
  }
}
```

Now I tried to put the code above in this section, and it ran every time the button was clicked, however, it only ran in the IDE, so my question is: what do I need to add in order to make the code run in the applet, specifically in the text area?

Comment: Please edit your code examples to show the class and method that contains each code snippet. See [mcve] for more tips on creating a useful code example.

Comment: I have edited the code snippets

Comment: That's better. You still have not shown the classes which contain the methods. This is especially important when writing a GUI program to show how you are using the classes from Swing. Also show your attempt and building the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by attempt, all I did was go on new class and made that into a JApplet Form

Comment: What methods do I need to show?

Comment: Please read the link in my first comment. Specifically, you need to show what you have done so far to create the GUI. Be sure that the code you show here compiles without any additional errors other than what you are asking about. At the moment, none of your code compiles because there is no class.

Comment: I think I have done what you asked

Comment: Getting closer. Now where's the code for the button and text area?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I have added the code @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Patience, young padawan. Now what is your question? You need to add an OnClickListener to your button and put the appropriate logic in that method.

Comment: I like the reference, and my question was how to get the output of the code to be in the applet, so just add the onclicklistener and add the code in it, is that what you mean? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: That is a good start. However, instead of using `System.out.println()` for output, you will need to figure out how to add text to the JTextArea.

Comment: I have gotten it work, as I used textField.setText(textField.getText() + whateverHere);, and now it displays the result in the text field rather than the IDE

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you found a solution. You should also look at the [append()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) method which can simplify your code a little.

Comment: Oh I see, append() will become useful for this project, thanks